# How do I create an encrypted archive containing specific files?

Tags: zip

How do I create a password protected archive containing all the files with the extension conf from `/etc`?

Answer (score 1):

Given that the question was tagged with `zip`, you're probably looking for something like this:

```
$ ls /etc/*.conf | xargs zip myfile.zip -e
```

Comment: Depending on the permissions of the files added to the zip file, you might need to execute as root.

Answer (score 1):

Considering a *very unlikely* scenario when `*.conf` filenames in `/etc` contain spaces, this is a safe way to zip them:

```
find /etc -name *.conf -print0 | xargs -0 zip archive.zip -e
```